# Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I'm experiencing a weird error with my PhoneGap app: every odd time I run the simulator (or the test deployed app on my phone), I get the error

```
Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

It works every even time I run the simulator. This has been happening since I first deployed my app. I was not using any plugins at the time, but since then I've been trying to get the Facebook iOS SDK working, and this probably isn't related but the times that my app actually succeeds to start up, I can't click anything.

God help me.

This *is* my first time building an iOS app, so this is probably a newbie mistake - before this my app was just a mobile website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a javascript redirect that was causing this. Avoid using `window.location = ???` on the initial pageload at all costs in PhoneGap :)

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced this issue. The Urls are case sensitive. So if you have `Login.html` as the file name, it shouldn't be `login.html` in the code.

Comment: After hours of debugging found it was due to this, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

`kill -9 ps ax | grep Simulator | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`

Try this line on the terminal and then run. Maybe there is a problem in simulator, it will resolve

Comment: It's easier to do `pkill Simulator` and without sending `-9` signal first, that's too brutal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. However, it was a different cause.

We have a webapp that uses clean urls. We use htaccess to automatically check for .html. That way our links in the code/url are just myapp.com/page1 vs myapp.com/page1.html

This caused me about an hour of headaches, as I began exploring the port over to phonegap. Nothing would work. I was brand new to phonegap, so I wasn't sure what it was. I did the whitelist, external hosts, etc. Then I realized I dont have the htaccess file in the phonegap directory and that I need complete links.

I know its specific. But for what its worth, there you have it.